# Insert into multiple rows on Multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Inserting rows into table one by one is more hardy and tedious instead of inserting rows into more than one tables at one time with just in single SQL query

Because I have 10 tables in which I need to insert rows so it would be more boring to put rows only in one table at a time rather than all rows inserts at all tables

So please suggest me a better query to insert all rows at all tables in one time

Comment: Oracle Express Edition  11G

Comment: "more boring"? This is clearly not your intention. Also you have to give a better description of your use-case if you want to get serious answers.

Comment: THe good news is that Oracle 11G does support multiple tables insert

Comment: You could use SSIS.

Comment: No sorry , I didn't mean to say boring , but regarding my context, is there any way to achieve what i exactly questioned above . Your cooperation in this regard will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

For multitable insert you can use the below syntax if you have to insert a limited set of records at 1 go:

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO AA(A,B,C,D,E,F) VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    INTO AB(A,B,C,D,E) VALUES (5,4,3,4,2)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```